# Install MariaDB 10.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, mariadb

I'm relatively new to the Linux. Can anyone please help me how to install MariaDB version 10.0 and not newer?

Answer (score 2):

You should do the following:

Create a MariaDB.list file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ with the following contents to add the MariaDB apt repository:

```
# MariaDB 10.0 repository list - created 2019-01-27 09:50 UTC
# http://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
deb [arch=amd64,arm64,ppc64el] http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu bionic main
deb-src http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu bionic main
```

And then:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mariadb-server
```

I hope this works for you.

Sources:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/installing-mariadb-deb-files/

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB 10.0 is not supported for Ubuntu 18.04 sadly :(

You can install MDB 10.0 in Ubuntu 16.04 or MDB 10.1 in 18.04:
https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=bionic--ubuntu_bionic&mirror=harukasan&version=10.0